# div stays on top but should move with the site

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll

I´m getting crazy here. I designed a site, scrolling from left to the right, but I can´t get the content for each ¨page¨ scrolling.
Instead the content sticks on top.
Please have a look [here](http://www.mototec.malleim.com)

The button (skull with pistons and info text) should stick on the page and move if navigation gets clicked

here is the code:

```
<div id="section_home" class="section_holder1"><!-- BEGIN SECTION "HOME -->
        <div class="container"><!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
            <div class="section_content"><!-- Begin Section Container -->
                 <div class="content_container"><!-- Begin Content -->
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                    <div class="sign1">
                        <a class="readmore"  href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End Content -->
            </div><!-- End Section Container -->
        </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
    </div><!-- END SECTION "HOME -->
```

Any idea what I´m doing wrong here?

Comment: css please (or fiddle)

Comment: i don't have the answer.. but i like ur site..

Answer (score 1):

Basically you problem is here:

```
.sign1 a.readmore {
    display: block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 67px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    z-index: 999999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(../img/bg-readmore.png);
    position: fixed; /* --> position fixed is not what you're looking for */
    top: 48%;
    right: 43%;
}
```

Settins `position:fixed` does exactly what you see (**fixing the element's position relative to the browser window..** it is no longer effected by page structure) you have in the middle all the buttons from all the frames on top of each other.

Try repositioning `.sign1 a.readmore` using `position:absolute`